# Copy System.Drawing.Image class without reference

Tags: c#, image, reference

I need to make copy of Image class. Tried `clone()`, but didn't work. Also googled about it and found `MemberwiseClone()`, but i think i can't access Image class. Also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696448/how-to-make-a-copy-of-an-object-in-c-sharp) solution, guess it didn't work. Any ideas how to copy Image class without reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Bitmap` (which inherits from `Image` has a constructor overload that creates a copy:

```
Bitmap copy = new Bitmap(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad. There was silly mistake. Solution below also works fine.

```
private Image DeepCopy(Image other)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                formatter.Serialize(ms, other);
                ms.Position = 0;
                return (Image)formatter.Deserialize(ms);
            }
        }
```

.

```
Image tempImg = DeepCopy(img);
```

Also, this works too:

```
Image tempImg = (Image)img.Clone();
```